# What is a good first web application development programming language?

Tags: web-services, web-applications, webserver

I am currently doing Computer Science degree and I have fair amount of experience in C#, Java, and C++ in desktop application development. And I want to start learning how to build applications that run in the web browser such as Google Docs and Blackboard Learn. What is the best technology to start with ? I know this is a broad question whose answer is usually "it depends on what you are trying to make" but I want to know what is good multipurpose language/technology just to start with  so I can get some experience and develop some foundation for transitioning my desktop skills to the web ? Many thanks for your responses !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to list all your requirements. After you are done with the requirements you can select what suits you the best. Current web applications use a cocktail of several technologies. The choice of technology should be purely based on your requirements, ease of use and budget constraints.

Of course, you have a plethora of several open source technologies to help you out. Biggies such as Facebook, Google too use open source. Since you are a student go for open source technologies.

This is a good link if you want to learn web from scratch : http://www.w3schools.com/

Thanks